# Exporting Swagger/OpenAPI to Postman collection with examples

Tags: swagger, postman, nestjs

I have a large codebase in NestJS for which I have used Swagger to document the API routes (`"@nestjs/swagger": "^3.1.0"`). However, the Swagger UI seems to be underpowered for such large projects and I would like to migrate to Postman. Here is what happens:

Take for example this model structure:

```
export class IApiGenericRequest {
    @ApiModelProperty({
        example: null,
        default: 0
    })
    appVersionCode: number;
    @ApiModelProperty({
        example: false,
        default: false
    })
    testerMode: boolean;
    @ApiModelProperty({
        example: 1,
        default: 1
    })
    appId: number;
}

export class IApiGenericRequestUserId extends IApiGenericRequest {
    @ApiModelProperty({
        example: 1,
        default: 1
    })
    userId: number;
}

class IApiEventsV2UserDetails extends IApiGenericRequestUserId {
    @ApiModelProperty({
        example: 1
    })
    eventId: number;
    @ApiModelProperty({
        example: false
    })
    loadMap: boolean;
}
```

Example route:

```
@Post('details')
@ApiResponse({
    status: 200,
    description: 'Get event user details',
    type: null
})
async details(@Res() res: Response, @Body() body: IApiEventsV2UserDetails) {
  // call service
}
```

In Swagger UI the request example is shown properly:

```
{
  "appVersionCode": null,
  "testerMode": false,
  "appId": 1,
  "userId": 25,
  "eventId": 5,
  "loadMap": false
}
```

When imported in Postman it looks like this:

```
{
    "appVersionCode": "<number>",
    "testerMode": "<boolean>",
    "appId": 1,
    "userId": 25,
    "eventId": "<number>",
    "loadMap": "<boolean>"
}
```

I can't figure out what happens here and how can it be fixed.